# Avoid white area on contour plot

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot contour plots and some of them show a white patch because of a change in sign of the points plotted. How can I make the contour plot show this change in sign without having to take the absolute of the values?

The data is the following:

```
axialP1plot= {{30, 0, 0.509185}, {60, 0, 0.474159}, {90, 0, 0.452413}, {120, 0, 
      0.450468}, {0, 0.6, 0.422016}, {30, 0.6, 0.365962}, {60, 0.6, 
      0.263496}, {90, 0.6, 0.200892}, {120, 0.6, 0.188312}, {0, 1.2, 
      0.316512}, {30, 1.2, 0.140834}, {60, 1.2, -0.129596}, {90, 
      1.2, -0.248149}, {120, 1.2, -0.246671}, {0, 1.8, 0.211008}, {30, 
      1.8, -0.454357}, {60, 1.8, -1.08961}, {90, 1.8, -1.13311}, {120, 
      1.8, -0.979351}, {0, 2.4, 0.105504}, {30, 2.4, -3.50926}, {60, 
      2.4, -3.56817}, {90, 2.4, -2.62564}, {120, 2.4, -1.96434}, {0, 2.9, 
      0.017584}, {30, 2.9, -13.3785}, {60, 2.9, -6.04938}, {90, 
      2.9, -3.59638}, {120, 2.9, -2.49518}, {0, 0, 0.52752}}
```

And the contour plot:

```
ListContourPlot[axialP1plot, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  Contours -> 10, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  PlotLabel -> Style["Axial Force on Plate 1", FontSize -> 14]]
```

Which yields:

[image]

Comment: specify `PlotRange -> All`. Its not the sign change but your one extreme negative value the the automatic setting has decided to exclude from the plot range.

Comment: Thank you @george2079. If I follow your suggestion there is no longer a white area. Is there a way to mark/highlight when the change in sign happens on the graph?

Comment: use  `ALL` and also explicitly list the contours you want to include zero (see @dantopa 's answer).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As george2079 say in his comment to your question, add the option `PlotRange -> All`

```
ListContourPlot[axialP1plot,
  PlotRange -> All,
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
  Contours -> 10,
  PlotLegends -> Automatic,
  PlotLabel -> "Axial Force on Plate 1"]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Surely there must be a similar question answered with `PlotRange -> All` of which this one may be marked a duplicate?

Answer (score 3):

Use `Contours -> {0}` to force the contour line at zero value.[image]

```
ListContourPlot[axialP1plot, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 Contours -> {0}, ContourStyle -> {Black, Thick}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 PlotLabel -> Style["Axial Force on Plate 1", FontSize -> 14]]
```