# Problem with color using ListDensityPlot

Tags: plotting, color

I have a small color problem ListDensityPlot.
I made the following code to plot my data. 
When I compare with the original one, I have a color problem... I lost information in the middle : I get a big white ring which I should not have...(as in the original one...) 
I don't see what I miss in my code since I didn't put any condition in the ColorFunction...

Here my raw data
https://share.orange.fr/#A105hQPNTk19d931b402

Here my code to import multiple files

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];

file = FileNames["*.dat", NotebookDirectory[]];

func[file_String /; FileExistsQ[file]] := 
 Module[{data, dataT}, data = Import[file, "Table", HeaderLines -> 2];
  dataT = Transpose[data];
  dataT = {dataT[[1]], dataT[[2]], dataT[[3]]}; 
  data = Transpose[dataT];
  graph = ListDensityPlot[data,
    PlotLabel -> FileBaseName[file],
    ColorFunction -> (ColorData["TemperatureMap"][#] &),
    PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, 
    LegendLabel -> "\[CapitalDelta]\[CapitalSigma]/\[CapitalDelta]\[CapitalOmega] \(Counts/Exp time)", LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, FontSize -> 18], 
      LegendMarkerSize -> 300, 
      LabelingFunction -> (Style[NumberForm[#, {Infinity, 2}], Black, 
          20] &)]];


  Print[GraphicsRow[{graph}, ImageSize -> 800, Spacings -> 30]];
  outputFileName = FileBaseName[file];
  Export[ToString[outputFileName] <> "_raw.jpeg", graph]
   ;
  ]

func /@ file
```

Here the results I get using my code...

[image: Picture I get from my code]

Comment: Have you seen this https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/116494/avoid-white-area-on-contour-plot?

Comment: I am so stupid...I didn't think to add `PlotRange -> All` ... Thanks a lot